# TCPDF Make Header Margin Wider Than Body

Tags: php, tcpdf

In TCPDF, I am trying to make the header go the full width of the page, but for there still to be margin everywhere else. Because the header is contained with the margins of the page, I am finding it hard to do this. How can it be done?

Comment: So you want to extend the header beyond the page margins? Have you tried with negative coordinates? Also you should show your code and probably upload the PDF file and link it that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You are correct. I just tried this: $pdf->SetMargins(10, 10, 10); $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(-10, -10, -10);, but it didn't work. I don't have the PDF yet because I'm just creating it.